# using $\sin x$ to get a function with range $[a,b]$

Tags: analysis

$\sin x$ is a nice function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose range is $[-1,1]$. can we 'adjust' it so that its range will be $[a,b]$. By 'adjusting' I mean changing the argument $x$ to some other argument which is a function of $x$ , or multiplying by a constant or adding a constant. For example $2x$, $2x^2$ or $\sin x$ in which case we will have $\sin(2x)$, $\sin(2x^2)$, $\sin(\sin x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the range of $\sin$ is $[-1, 1]$, not $[0, 1]$. Second, by adjusting the argument as you propose, i.e. composing $\sin$ with another function $f$ on the right and getting $\sin(f(x))$, you can only make the range smaller. You cannot turn it into anything larger, like $[-10, 10]$, because no matter what you put in the argument of $\sin$, the result will always be inside $[-1, 1]$.

*UPDATE:* Now I've also noticed that you allow multiplying by and adding constants, i.e. composing $\sin$ with an affine function on the *left*. That can indeed give you the desired range. For instance, the range of $$\frac{b+a}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}\sin x$$ is $[a, b]$.

Comment: I have edited the question. I type the question incompletely. sorry.

Comment: Let your function be $g$. $g(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{b+a}{2}$ which is need not be a point in $[a,b]$. then how is range of $g$ is $[a,b]$? please explain.

Comment: Here's an explanation (not a rigorous proof). Denote $h(x) = \frac{b+a}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}\sin x$. Observe that $h(\pi/2) = \frac{b+a}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2} = b$, and $h(-\pi/2) = \frac{b+a}{2} - \frac{b-a}{2} = a$. All the other values are in-between.

Comment: Also, to address your last comment, $\frac{b+a}{2}$ is *always* in $[a, b]$. In fact, it is the middle point of that segment. (I'm assuming $a \leq b$, so our segment is nonempty).

Comment: sorry. sorry. sorry. I have confused it lot. now got it perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x$ will always lie between [-1,1]. However if you want to change the range of a function defined as y=$\sin x$, you can rewrite it as $$y=|c\sin x+d|$$ such that c+d=b and c-d=b.

We have 
$$\sin x=\begin{cases}
|c-d|=a, & \text{ if $\sin x$=-1} \\
|c+d|=b, & \text{if $\sin x$=1} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: A couple of tiny mistakes: $\sin(x)$ is not always in $[0,1]$ and $c\sin(x)+a$ has range $[a-c,a+c]$.